# Get the input of type "number" from each row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem during the recovery of type input in a table, i can't resolve this.

```
$('#genere tbody').on('click' ,'#calcul' ,function(){
        let currentrow = $(this).closest('tr');
        let evol = currentrow.find('td:eq(2)').val();
        console.log(evol);
    })
```

The result I want is that when I click on calculate, I get the value of the input.

Here is the HTML code:
NB : The manipulated data are recovered with ajax :

```
$('table#genere tbody').append(`
    <tr>
        <td><div id='labo'>${obj.labos}</div></td>
        <td>${obj.articles}</td>
        <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" min="0" placeholder="1.20" value="" id="evolution"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="actif" data-articles="${obj.articles}" value="${obj.actif}"></td>
        <td><div id ="qte">${obj.qteder}</div></td>
        <td><div id="objectif">${obj.objectif}</div></td>
        <td><button type="button" id="calcul" class="btn btn-outline-success">calculer</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: This is english-only site, could you please translate your question to english please?

Comment: Please ask your question in English.

Comment: Yes -- please wait

Comment: Including your HTML for context will also help, but if `td:eq(2)` always contains an `<input type="number">`, it looks like you’re just looking for `.find('td:eq(2) > input').val()`.

Comment: Note that ids should also be unique within a document; things will break. Use classes instead, e.g. `id="calcul"` → `class="calcul"` and `'.calcul'` as the selector for event delegation.

Comment: Thanks for all : it's done now. 

i change my jquery code  to `.find('td:eq(2) > input').val( )`

Comment: You are targeting wrong element to get a value, `td` instead of `input`. Try below:

Just replaced the line:

    `let evol = currentrow.find('td:eq(2)').val();`

with

   `let evol = currentrow.find('input[type="number"]').val();`

I hope this will help you.